# How to create an object from datareader from two tables (sql statemens)

Tags: c#, datareader

I have two classes `Car` and `Drivers`:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public IList<Driver> Event { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

I get the values from TWO SQL-Statemens (e.g. Select * from car; select * from driver). I can fill the first one with:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    _results.Add(new TaskModel(rdr));
    //new TaskModel(rdr); 
}
```

where `_results` is:

```
private ObservableCollection<Car> _results = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
```

Constructor for Car looks like:

```
public Car(IDataRecord record)
{
    this.CarId = Convert.ToInt32(record["CARID"]);
    this.Color = (string)record["COLOR"];
}
```

I'm asking myself how to fill the datareader with two statemens and refer in the constructor to get the whole object (Car with Driver)

Comment: Please adjust the sample code, it's really hard to tell what's going on with all the "Enter Code here" statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about retrieving all the data in one go, as in

```
SELECT * FROM Car INNER JOIN Driver ON Car.Id = Driver.CarId
```

And then create your object graph from there on?

Also I wouldn't use the datareader in the constructor, use a third object to construct the object from a database.

[JOIN Fundamentels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx).

Comment: BennyM - many thanks for your answer. Could you give me a hint what you mean by saying "use a third object to construct"?

Comment: Google either for data access object or repository if you want to do it more domain driven devolopment style. If you're just starting out a dao will probably be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the data mapper pattern.  You are creating a tight coupling between your domain and data access.  You don't want to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the query to an inner join as @BennyM suggests then you can join the objects using LiNQ instead. First create one `List<Car> Cars` and one `List<Driver> Drivers` and fill them using datareader(s), then join them like this:

```
from c in Cars
join d in Drivers on d.CommonKey = c.CommonKey //Your code samples doesn't mention any key connecting the two objects, so please adjust this to whatever it should be.
select new { c, d }
```

This is of course a less good solution than fixing the actual SQL-query...